# Proper way to retrieve list data asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, object-model

I have done this in the past using [jQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function and the SharePoint web services, but I'm curious if it is considered a better practice to use the [Javascript Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538253.aspx)?

Also, is it secure to use the Javascript Object Model on a public facing site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no harm in using jQuery - JS Object Model is given my MSFT so you can use that in case if you freshely develop the application which doesnt have jQuery.

Also, you hv more control  when you use Javascript Object Model - by utilising all pre defined methods !